# I would like to learn how to data analyse, but I am having trouble with conditional statements and extracting data to plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, data-analysis

Basically, I am new to data analysis and I got a dataset that I would like to analyze and get some graphs to test out hypotheses and learn more about the data I got about the Olympics.

Now, I would like to find out which age gets the most gold, silver, and bronze medals and the same goes for height.

This is the code I have created, I think it works (i am not sure) but takes like 20 minutes to process and the format is weird which gives me trouble putting in a graph. I would like to know how I can cut the processing time significantly shorter and how I would be able to graph it ->

```
#calculating number of medals each person has
j=0
i=0
height_gold=[0]*230
height_silver=[0]*230
height_bronze=[0]*230

while(i<271116):
    while(j<230):
        if df.iloc[i,4]==j:
            if df.iloc[i,14]=='Gold':
                height_gold[j]=height_gold[j]+1
            if df.iloc[i,14]=='Silver':
                height_silver[j]=height_silver[j]+1
            if df.iloc[i,14]=='Bronze':
                height_bronze[j]=height_bronze[j]+1
        j=j+1
        #print('new_age')
    i=i+1
    j=0
    #print('new_row')

print(height_gold)
print(height_silver)
print(height_bronze)
```

Also, I would very much like to know how I would be able to find out which sport gets the most medals, which Olympic year gave out the most medals, and which country gets the most medals.

Now that I am here, I would also like to ask what else I could find out from this csv.file here ->

[the CSV file/data I am using to get data to plot a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8qST.png)

Comment: Your code takes so long because you're running `271116 * 230` iterations of your if statements.

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of df contents

Comment: As a general rule, and I make no comment on your code, you should always be testing on small-ish datasets so that you can rapidly iterate through the cycle of thinking-developing-testing while you work out your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you’re finding `j` in an inefficient way (checking all 230 possibilities). You can just set `j` to `df.iloc[i, 4]`. You’ve also built your own `for` loop, which I’ve fixed here as well.

```py
height_gold = [0] * 230
height_silver = [0] * 230
height_bronze = [0] * 230

for i in range(271116):
    j = df.iloc[i, 4]
    if df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Gold':
        height_gold[j] += 1
    elif df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Silver':
        height_silver[j] += 1
    elif df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Bronze':
        height_bronze[j] += 1

print(height_gold)
print(height_silver)
print(height_bronze)
```

If you have non-integers, this should deal with it:

```py
height_gold = [0] * 230
height_silver = [0] * 230
height_bronze = [0] * 230

for i in range(271116):
    j = df.iloc[i, 4]
    try:
        j = int(round(j))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Gold':
        height_gold[j] += 1
    elif df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Silver':
        height_silver[j] += 1
    elif df.iloc[i, 14] == 'Bronze':
        height_bronze[j] += 1
print(height_gold)
print(height_silver)
print(height_bronze)
```

Comment: Hey LeopardShark, thanks so much for helping but when I ran the code, it gave me the error -> KeyError: nan

Comment: nah, it doesn't

Comment: I told you, I got a KeyError: nan

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeffery Keough/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Data Analysis/olympics_stacksedit.py", line 31, in <module>
    medals[df.iloc[i,14]][df.iloc[i,4]] += 1
KeyError: nan

Comment: For non-integers, it still doesn't work. I am sorry but I just don't understand. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeffery Keough/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Data Analysis/olympics_stacksedit.py", line 38, in <module>
    height_gold[j] += 1
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Comment: Try now (changed `round(j)` to `int(round(j))`).

Comment: bruh, thanks a lot. not only does it work but it also makes sense for me. Thank yo so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have some improvements that would significantly speed things up:

- Your inner loop (the one that counts to 230) is unnecessary. You could use the value from `df.iloc[i,4]` as index in the arrays.
- You could also use the color of the medal as index into the list of medal counts.

With these, you get the following code:

```
medals={'Gold': [0]*230,
        'Silver': [0]*230,
        'Bronze': [0]*230}

for i in range(271116):
    country = int(df.iloc[i,4])
    medals[df.iloc[i,14]][country] += 1

print(medals['Gold'])
print(medals['Silver'])
print(medals['Bronze'])
```

Comment: Hello EvertW, thanks for helping but the improvements you gave but it didnt work. It gave me the error of: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Comment: I have modified the code, that should hopefully solve the problem. The line was getting a bit long, so I split it in two parts to make it more readable.

Comment: Hey EvertW, sorry man it still doesn't work. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeffery Keough/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Data Analysis/olympics_stacksedit.py", line 53, in <module>
    medals[df.iloc[i,14]][country] += 1
KeyError: nan

Comment: There probably is something wrong with the way you read your table: there is a NaN at a place where an index is expected... Try to filter incorrect lines before applying this algorithm.